# install express with npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, npm

I recently installed nodejs version 0.10.26 on ubuntu 64 bit. node -v and npm -v commands run fine and I can see the correct versions. When I do a `$ sudo npm install -g express`
 the installation goes fine. But when I try to create a project with express as `$ express myProject` I get an error saying

> The program 'express' is currently not installed. You can install it
>   by typing: sudo apt-get install node-express

Do I have to include some path in $PATH in order to run express? Please help.

Comment: check this post http://wiki.workassis.com/installing-express-with-nodejs/ here you can see how to setup express and also a small helloworld application

Answer (score 51, accepted):

With Express 4, the application generator was removed and is now available as 'express-generator.' So you need to `npm install -g express-generator` instead.

Comment: why npm commands takes too much time in my ubuntu 14.04 64 bit :(
sometime it stucks saying nothing for a long time

Comment: From @mscdex comment above, Now, the updated documentation is at http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html

Comment: after I run this command, when I type `express` it respond with `The program 'express' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install node-express`

Comment: Thanks for saving the day !

Answer (score 1):

Enter the command in your terminal

```
npm install --save express
```