# node.js: can't install express properly

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having trounble with installing `express`. After I do `npm install express`, `express` is still not visible. I.e. I'm unable to do `express appname`. I'm running Win7. What is done incorrectly?

**UPD.** I'm following [this](http://dailyjs.com/2010/11/08/node-tutorial-2/) tutorial

Comment: It looks like you're following a tutorial, if you are it would be helpful to know the url to it. Otherwise providing the code you are using will help us to help you better.

Comment: Try installing it globally with `-g`

Comment: Its possibly a path problem (like you pointed out in the comment), but doing ```express something``` is only a convenient way to make a default app, you can just copy the code from an example like [this](http://www.mfranc.com/node-js/node-js-simple-web-server-with-express/) to get started

Comment: also duplicating [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097826/install-express-with-npm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

since express 4.0 the CLI tools are not part of the main express package anymore. if you want to have the generator you have to install it separately:

```
    npm install -g express-generator
```

[see here](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#executable)

Comment: Spent a couple of hours trying to figure this one out. They really should update their installation guide.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the :

`express appname`

command, you should install express the following way :

`sudo npm install -g express`

or just:

`npm install -g express`

if you are not on a UNIX system. Otherwise if you already did an :

`npm install express`

you can run this command:

`./node_modules/express/bin/express appname`

from your project's root directory.

Comment: I think, I'll add `node_modules/express/bin/express` to path